# How go we get feature information (like centroid) after the map is rendered and fitToBounds method is called

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

Following is the actual objective.

-Draw labels on the polygon shapes (like show country name or state name)
-These names to should the middle aligned to the centroid of the polygon
-Avoid overlapping of the labels (before we render a marker we check if this marker will overlap with any marker already rendered. If yes, it should not render the marker)

We wrote a sample and all of the above points are addressed. Following the code.

- labels are rendered on the map using marker feature. we generate the HTML and flex classes to center the text to the centroid of the polygon.
- to avoid overlapping we make note pixel coordinates the markers created. Each div is a rectangle with minX,minY,maxX,maxY coordinates and we check if rectangles intersect.

```
var geojson_layer = new L.geoJson(geojson_data, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.geometry.type.toLowerCase() === "multipolygon") {
      var largest = _.maxBy(
        feature.geometry.coordinates,
        r => r[0].length
      );
      p = polylabel(largest, 1.0);
    } else {
      p = polylabel(feature.geometry.coordinates, 1.0);
      console.log(p.toString());
    }
    lon = p[0];
    lat = p[1];
    if (lat && lon) {
      var latLng = L.latLng([lat, lon]);
      var point = mymap.latLngToContainerPoint(latLng);
      var titleText =
        '<svg width="300" height="14"><text x="50%" y="8" fill="black" text-anchor="middle">' +
        feature.properties.name +
        ":more text added" +
        "</text></svg>";
      var rectArea = new RectangleArea(
        point.x - 150,
        point.x + 150,
        point.y,
        point.y + 14
      );
      var canRender = true;
      labelRects.forEach(element => {
        if (element.rectanglesIntersect(rectArea)) {
          canRender = false;
          return;
        }
      });
      if (canRender) {
        labelRects.push(rectArea);
        var label2 = L.marker([lat, lon], {
          icon: L.divIcon({
            iconSize: null,
            zIndexOffset: 100000,
            html:
              "<div style='position: relative; left:-50%; display: flex; align-items:center; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center;'>" +
              titleText +
              "</div>"
          })
        }).addTo(mymap);
      }
    }
  }
}).addTo(mymap);
```

All of this works fine except for one problem. In the sample, we set the map center and zoom level like this.

```
var mymap = L.map("map", { center: [41, -98], zoom: 5 });
```

In the real application, we don't set zoom level like this. We call `fitToBounds` method on the layer. This is the problem the above it fails to give us the pixel point if we do not set the zoom level upfront.

Anyone has any idea on how we can get the feature collection and its centroid after the layer is rendered and `fitToBounds` method is called? Is there any other way of achieving the objective?